# Why I am getting error unbound variable cygwin bash error

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

Following is the my script ( snippet )

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o xtrace
set -o pipefail

ARGUMENT=$1
```

I am trying to run with cygwin bash and Getting following error.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -c /cygdrive/c/test.sh ARGUMENT1
```

Getting following error

```
+ set -o pipefail
/cygdrive/c/test.sh: line 8: $1: unbound variable
```

Comment: Your command should work if you omit `-c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing an argument to `test.sh`, since the argument is not included in the `-c` option value that you're passing to `bash`. Just add quotes to fix this:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -c "/cygdrive/c/test.sh ARGUMENT1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `set -o nounset` (a simpler way to achieve this would be `set -u`), you ask bash to raise an error whenever you refer to a variable which has not been set.

In

```
ARGUMENT=$1
```

the variable `1` does not have a value; hence the error.

Since you want to ensure at the calling site that your script is executed via bash, the idea to use `-c` is not good anyway, as in this case, the #! line would determine the shell to be used. You could write

```
bash -l /cygdrive/c/test.sh "my argument"
```

and this would pass *my argument* as first argument to your script.

A further possibility is to make this argument optional, and provide a default value for it. In this case, you would write the assignment as

```
ARGUMENT=${1:-default value}
```

With this construct, bash would not complain about an unset variable either.